# How to concatenate a link in a javascript function with a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to concatenate a link in a javascript function with a php variable. But whatever a try to write after ""+ doesn't get displayed and the whole program stops working.  The variable is defined in a different page. I tried REQUEST to access to it, but it's not working.

```
function popupEvent(){
    $('#btnClose').unbind("click"); 
    $('#btnClose').click(function(){
    window.location = SITEURL+"cart/rollPdf/?POrderNo="+implode(',', $orderIDArr); 
  window.open(ord,'winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');             

        return false
    });
}
```

Comment: That are two different languages, and two of such kind that you can not mix them. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/168214/367456 on how to deal with that. And just another hint: We have tons of material in this Q&A site already about that topic, I bet with a little searching and browsing you'll spot something to read in your very fashion and mood of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use PHP variable into JS, you need echo it. Ex, `<?php echo implode(',', $orderIDArr);?>`

In your code try Like this,

```
function popupEvent(){
    $('#btnClose').unbind("click"); 
    $('#btnClose').click(function(){
    window.location = SITEURL+"cart/rollPdf/?POrderNo=<?php echo implode(',', $orderIDArr);?>"; // Changed here
  window.open(ord,'winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');             

        return false
    });
}
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem...

**EDIT:**

```
function popupEvent(){
    $('#btnClose').unbind("click"); 
    $('#btnClose').click(function(){
    ord = SITEURL+"cart/rollPdf/?POrderNo=<?php echo implode(',', $orderIDArr);?>"; // Changed here
  window.open(ord,'winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');             

        return false
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not working man :/

Comment: The link should show a number after =. But it is showing whatever was typed in the echo.

Comment: Do you really have value in `$orderIDArr` variable while page loading?

Comment: It's in a different php file.

Comment: Wherever it is. The variable scope must be available at the before this JS load. Thats all...

Comment: i passed a static variable in this and it is running fine. But somehow it is not able to access $orderIDArr :/

Comment: Which means the variable scope is not available at right place. Review your code and make the variable scope available before the js script loaded.